# how to show a loading gif while downloadable file is being prepared?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a link `<a href='/download.php' target='_blank'>Download</a>`, and it takes time to begin the as for the preparation of file to be downloaded. i want to show a loading animation soon after the user click on download button. tried to find the solution , but failed. plz guide / help. the last i tried is

```
<style>
  div#page_loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 99;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    src='https://i.imgur.com/4j3qvX0.gif'
  }
</style>

<a onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('page_loader')
  .style.display='block';"
  href='/download.php'
  target='_blank'>Download</a>
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code, because it was originally unreadable. Once formatted, it's clear that you need to fix the image source because `src=...` is not valid CSS syntax.

Comment: You can show an image, but page navigation is going to kill it.

Comment: i think somthing like on click the download link, a text msg fade in "plz wait", and id fade out when download begins will be more easy. any clue to get this done ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this with CSS animations

```js
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
}

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
/* Center the loader */

#loader {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
  border: 10px solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 10px solid #f3f3f3;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}


#myDiv {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myFunction()" href="#" target="_self">Download</a>

<div id="loader"></div>

<div style="display:none;" id="myDiv" class="animate-bottom">
  <h2>Tada!</h2>
  <p>Some text in my newly loaded page..</p>
</div>
```